# How does one iterate over all rows and apply updates in EF Core effectively?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

I need to iterate over an entire `Artist` table that has a 1-to-many relation ship to `Songs`.  The details for the artists and list of songs are stored in a file and this path is saved on the `Artist` table, `DataFilePath`.

The code is below is my attempt at this, but it gives the following exception:
`System.InvalidOperationException: Connection is busy`

```
// Artist to Songs is a 1 to many relationship
foreach(var artist in db.Artist.Include(x => x.Songs)) 
{
    try
    {
        // Load details for artist and songs from artist.DataFilePath
        var fileData = LoadArtistFile(artist.DataFilePath);

        // UpdateArtists() will
        //  - update each property for the Artists entity
        //  - add any new Songs 
        //  - update each Song property for existing songs
        UpdateArtist(artist, fileData);
        
        db.SaveChanges();
    } catch (Exception err)
    {
        _logger.LogError(err.Message);
    }
}
```

2 questions:

1. How do I fix the code above to avoid the Connection is busy problem?  (I've tried a number of other variations including lazy loading and explicit loading).
2. If the artists table were millions of rows and therefore songs table were 10's of millions of rows - is this still the most effective way to update the both tables? (staying within EF Core)

#### UPDATE

I've taken David's answer and modified the approach to use batching because I'm not able to load all rows into memory at once...

```
int batchSize = 50; // batch of 50 gave best performance (vs 10 and 100)
int currentBatch = 0;
// get the max id from the database for a stopping point (probably a better way to do this)
int maxId = GetMaxArtistID();
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
    using (var db = new Context())
        {
            var artists = db.Artists
                .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                .Skip(currentBatch++ * batchSize)
                .Take(batchSize)
                .Include(x => x.Songs)
                .ToList();
            var ids = String.Join(", ", artists.Select(x => x.Id));
            Console.WriteLine($"Working on batch:{currentBatch} ids: {ids}");
            foreach (var artist in artists)
            {
                var fileData = LoadArtistFile(artist.DataFilePath)
                UpdateArtist(artist, fileData);
                if (artist.Id >= maxId)
                    done = true;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I fix the code above to avoid the Connection is busy problem?

Load the data into memory before iterating it.  eg

```
foreach(var artist in db.Artist.Include(x => x.Songs).ToList())
```

> If the artists table were millions of rows and therefore songs table were 10's of millions of rows - is this still the most effective way to update the both tables?  (staying within EF Core)

EF itself doesn't do server-side data modification, so that's really the only way.  But at some scale you want to *not* use EF, and load your data file into a table and perform the update on the server side.

Comment: Thanks David.  At some point I'll have to switch this worker service to non-EF, but wanted to get something working first.  I've modified the approach a little posted in the UPDATED section of the original question that performs some batching as I can't load all rows into memory at once.